# IF Statement gaps

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I have a typical nested if-elif block of *python* code. Why does my output require the input be entered multiple times before returning the next statement?

```
Var = str(input("Type in a greeting: "))
if Var.upper().lower() == "Hello".upper().lower():
    input("Hello there! How are you doing? ")
    if input().upper().lower() == "Good".upper().lower():
        exit("Thats Great! Have a good day. ")
    elif input().upper().lower() == "Bad".upper().lower():
        input("What's wrong? ")
elif Var.upper().lower() == "Hi".upper().lower():
    print("Hi there!")
elif Var.upper().lower() == "Hey".upper().lower():
    print("Hey there!")
```

Here is the output:

```
Type in a greeting: hello
Hello there! How are you doing? bad
bad
bad
What's wrong?
```

Comment: Which language is this? Please [edit] your question to add the language tag

Comment: You're calling `input` multiple times. Are you intending to use `Var`? Every use of `input` will block until it gets input.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Thanks @jpp for advice.
As many times as you'll call the `input()` function, it'll prompt user for an input.

change

```
input("Hello there! How are you doing? ")
if input().upper().lower() == "Good".upper().lower():
```

to

```
input2 = input("Hello there! How are you doing? ")
if input2.lower() == "Good".lower():
```

For all cases

P.S.: You don't really need to do  `upper().lower()`.

Just doing `lower()` will work just as fine.

Comment: it didn't make sense to me too, but then that was not his question.